# Troubles with pointer to methods

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I'm just learning C++ and I'm having difficulties regarding pointers to methods. Lets say:

```
class One {
public:
int Add (int a, int b) {return a+b;}
};

typedef int (One::*pAdd) (int, int);

class Other {
public:
int Next (pAdd funct, int c){ return funct (c, 1);}

};

int main (){

One one;
Other other;

other.Next(one.Add, 2);

return 0;
}
```

I have a number of problems, as reported by my MinGW. First, I'm not invoking funct correctly, as compiler insists on using .* or ->* . Have no idea how to incorporate this request and any help is welcomed. Now, I could solve my problems by making methods static to use c-style pointers or pass objects and invoke methods from within Next, but I want to understand pointers to methods. Basically, I'm puzzled why one.Add is not an acceptable input. Method to call is unambiguously defined (.Add) and conforms my typedef. Also, I'm providing instance of class (one) from typedef thus providing context in which method is to be executed. But compiler output looks like I didn't only miss the syntax, but like I missed the concept. So, how to pass pointer to method with object as context as a single argument?

Comment: I just realized ... had them both opened and posted on a wrong tab. My apologizes to the community, how do I delete the question?

Comment: @gxs just let it get migrated.

Comment: Hi gxs, A moderator will be notified so that your question can be moved automatically to StackOverflow. This is Programmers and is a site for conceptual questions about software development. For more information see the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 6):

The main problem here is that member functions are not associated with an object instance, they are just function pointers with a slightly different signature.

So, when you want to call a member function you need two things: a **pointer to the member function** and the **object instance** in which to call it.

I changed your code sample a bit:

```
#include <iostream>

class One {
public:
    int Add (int a, int b) {return a+b;}
};

typedef int (One::*pAdd) (int, int);

class Other {
public:
    int Next (One one, pAdd funct, int c){
        return (one.*funct)(c, 1);
    }
};

int main (){
    One one;
    Other other;

    std::cout << other.Next(one, &One::Add, 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And [it works](http://ideone.com/tnquK) now. It can probably be improved a bit, but I think you can take it from here.

I recommend that you read [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) section of the [c++ faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html), which explains this very well.

Answer (score 1):

> So, how to pass pointer to method with object as context as a single argument?

Using just member-function pointers, you can't. Although your syntax looks like something that should do that, it just isn't allowed. You need an object to apply the function to:

```
class Other {
public:
    int Next (pAdd funct, One & o, int c){ return (o.*funct) (c, 1);}
}

int main (){
    One one;
    Other other;
    other.Next(&One::Add, one, 2);
}
```

If you want to create a function object that calls a particular member function of a particular object, then one possibility is to use `std::bind` (or `boost::bind` if you can't use C++11 yet):

```
#include <functional>

class Other {
public:
    int Next (std::function<int(int,int)> funct, int c){ return funct (c, 1);}
};

int main (){
    One one;
    Other other;

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    other.Next(std::bind(&One::Add, &one, _1, _2), 2);
}
```

or a lambda:

```
other.Next([&](int a, int b){return one.Add(a,b);}, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to members need an instance to operate on. Essentially, they are functions which take an addition parameter which becomes the implicit `this` pointer. To call a function through a pointer to member for the current object you can use code like this:

```
(this->*funct)(c, 1);
```

(you'd access member variables similarly but without a function call).

The object you call the member on isn't part of the pointer to member. As a result you need to get it something like this:

```
&One::Add
```

This becomes more interesting if the member function is overloaded: in this case you need to provide a context from which the overload can be determined when taking the address. I tupically use a `static_cast<>()` for this:

```
static_cast<int (One::*)(int,int)>(&One::Add)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of problems here: `one.Add` is a member function and
you cannot just invoke it. You need to have a pointer to the class to
invoke it on as well. Also, you need to use the special `operator.*`
or `operator->*`. You can also not take the address of a bound member
function.

All in all, you should use a template and `boost/std::bind` to make
all this bearable or stay away from it.

Here is modified, working code:

```
class One {
public:
  int Add (int a, int b) {return a+b;}
};

typedef int (One::*pAdd) (int, int);

class Other {
public:
  int Next (One* one, pAdd funct, int c){ return (one->*funct)(c, 1);}
};

int main (){

  One one;
  Other other;

  other.Next(&one, &One::Add, 2);

  return 0;
}
```